# CsvHelper: Read/Write Collection as Repeated CSV Columns

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper and I want to be able to read/write collections as repeated columns.  For example, given:

```
public class MyCsv
{
   public string A { get; set; }
   public List<string> Bs { get; set; }
}

var csv = new MyCsv { A = "a", Bs = new List { "b1", "b2" } };
```

I want `csv` to be serialized (using CsvHelper) as:

```
A,B,B
a,b1,b2
```

And then I need to be able to read the serialized CSV, again using CsvHelper.

The catch here is that I need this to be part of platform that does not expose `CsvHelper`, so the solution cannot be, for example, a sequence of `WriteField` calls.  **It needs to be accomplished using a `ClassMap` so the consumer can provide an object and a custom `ClassMap`.** . So the solution would be to define a `ClassMap` then use `CsvHelper` like this:

```
csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(myMap);
csvWriter.WriteRecords(myObject);
```

I've tried using a custom `ClassMap` with a custom mapping, something like: `Map(m => m.Bs).Name("B").Index(0, 1);`.  But this appends indices and requires knowing the number of columns ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a `ClassMap` for reading.  But I can't think of a way to create a `ClassMap` for writing that does what you want.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("A,B,B");
        writer.WriteLine("a,b1,b2");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var myMap = new MyCsvMap();

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(myMap);

        var records = csv.GetRecords<MyCsv>().ToList();
    }    
}

public class MyCsv
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public List<string> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class MyCsvMap : ClassMap<MyCsv>
{
    public MyCsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.A);
        Map(m => m.Bs).ConvertUsing(row => {
            var result = new List<string>();
            var headers = row.Context.HeaderRecord;
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (headers[i] == "B")
                {
                    result.Add(row.GetField(i));
                }
            }
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```